# Mongoengine - selecting error

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I am making an API which uses Mongoengine (MongoDB) and Flask.

I have a problem. I have a mongodb collection - schema:

```
class Word(EmbeddedDocument):
    word_id = IntField()
    word = StringField()
    translation = StringField()
    strength = IntField()
    meta = {'collection': 'users'}

    def to_dict(self):
        return mongo_to_dict(self)

class User(Document):
    user_id = IntField()
    username = StringField()
    email = EmailField()
    password = StringField()
    words = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Word))
    meta = {'collection': 'users',
    'ordering': ['-user_id']
```

i can show word with word_id with url api/users/xxx/words/
when i delete word with id 5, and collection will look like this

```
[
    {
        "username": "xxx",
        "password": "yyy",
        "words": [
            {
                "translation": "ajlkjbc", 
                "strength": 1, 
                "word": "abjlkc", 
                "word_id": 1
            }, 
            {
                "translation": "ajlkjbc", 
                "strength": 1, 
                "word": "ahkjc", 
                "word_id": 2
            }, 
            {
                "translation": "aklbc", 
                "strength": 5, 
                "word": "jklc", 
                "word_id": 3
            }, 
            {
                "translation": "afdfsc", 
                "strength": 1, 
                "word": "acjj", 
                "word_id": 4
            }, 
            {
                "translation": "dsadf", 
                "strength": 1, 
                "word": "dvdsf", 
                "word_id": 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem is when i go to url api/users/xxx/words/6
It doesn't work.

My code for this url is

```
@app.route('/api/users/<username>/words/<int:word_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_words(username):
     user = User.objects(username=username)
     l_user = user.to_json()
     decoded = json.loads(l_user)
     return Response(json.dumps(decoded[0]["words"][word_id-1], sort_keys=False, indent=4),
                mimetype='application/json')
```

It doesn't work if I delete some word in the middle.

Comment: Isn't the word_id still 6? You have to get by value or maintain strict order in the list yourself... I don't think you can mix the two...

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. I want to keep word_id same. So when I want to delete word with word_id 4, I want to keep word_id of others because words are synchronized with client (Backbone collection). So when I want to for example delete word with url api/words/xxx/words/6, which is already in client it won't work because it will be different in database. With your solution if I had 100 words and i would like to delete word with word_id 50, i have to rewrite 50 words, and then i have to send my new words to the client again and rewrite models on client again. I think that this is time consuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to filter out the matching item by id or returning a 404 if not existing eg:

```
@app.route('/api/users/<username>/words/<int:word_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_words(username):
     user = User.objects(username=username)
     word = [word for word user.words if word.word_id == word_id]
     if not word:
        return abort(404)
     return Response(word[0].to_json(sort_keys=False, indent=4),
                     mimetype='application/json')
```